# Forms using class table inheritance in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Flow question here... Assume I have an abstract `Profile` class and a `Principal` class that extends it, using class table inheritance, setup in Doctrine.

What is the best practice I would then use for creating the entities from a form since I am using inheritance? (i.e. I am creating a `Principal`, not it's `Profile` parent)

When I use the `doctrine:generate:crud` function from console it doesn't give me much since all of the properties currently live on the parent class and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to go about this. Here's my pass at it:

- Create my form type class with the fields I need to capture based on the parent.
- Create a controller and action to house my submit and use the Doctrine `EntityManager` to create a `Principal`, not a `Profile`
- Create my route to point to the controller
- Secure my route and/or controller

**Is that right?**

I am aware of Sonata but I'd rather not use a predefined bundle for this because I want to learn the ins and outs before making contributed bundle choices.

*P.S. I am getting the hang of Symfony2 thanks to the excellent docs and some key supporters here on the stack. Thank you for your help so far. I hope to repay it once I learn the system.*

Comment: In general you are right and you can also [reduce code duplication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html) for all common properties eventually shared with other user types

Comment: @gp_sflover, this approach makes all the *_SET_DATA listeners in embedded form not working( Spend couple of days to solve this but still no results (